# How to scrape content?

Tags: web-scraping

I created the following code to fetch the content:

```
import requests

r = requests.post(url='https://icecat.us/index.php/product/offers')

print r
print r.content
```

Requests returns HTTP Response Code 200 OK.
But r.content is empty, thus no content is retrieved, even though the response in the Developer tools is surely not empty.

What am I missing? Why is the content not retrieved correctly?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `request.get` call requires `params`, not `data`. `data` is for `request.post`.

```
import requests

payload = {
    'num' : '37963146',
    'lang' : 'us',
    'offers_country' : '0'
}

r = requests.get(
    url='https://icecat.us/index.php/product/offers',
    params=payload,
    headers={
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
)

print r
print r.content
```

BTW, I saw this posted on Upwork.